# React.useCallback() for chained anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lambda, react-hooks, memoization

Often, in order to pass an `onChange` callback function to a component you do something like this:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}

return (
  <Component onChange={handleChange} />
)
```

If you don't want the `Component` to render every time the main component does, you must wrap it in a `React.useCallback()` hook as follow:

```js
const handleChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}, [])

return (
  <Component onChange={handleChange} />
)
```

In a case where this input is generated in a for loop based on a list, you want the callback to know about the source of the change. The most common way of passing the information is by chaining lambdas as follow:

```js
const fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']

const handleChange = (fieldName) => (e) => {
  console.log(`${fieldName}: `, e.target.value)
}

return (
  <>
    {fields.map((x) => <Component onChange={handleChange(x)} />}
  </>
)
```

But in this case, it is kind of impossible to memoize the outer and inner lambdas while keeping the entire context in the function with a `React.useCallback()` hook.

In most cases, I have control on the component and change the callback to include the wanted data, but often it happens that the component is from a library (i.g. Material-UI) and, therefore, cannot be modified.

In what way could this callback be entirely memoized with React Hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate event handlers for each elements, and memoized the array of event handlers. When create the elements, take the relevant event handler by it's index:

```js
const { memo, useMemo } = React

const Demo = ({ fields }) => {
  const handlers = useMemo(() => 
    fields.map(fieldName => e => {
      console.log(`${fieldName}: `, e.target.value)
    })
  , [fields])

  return (
    <div>
      {
        fields.map(
          (fieldName, i) => (
            <input key={fieldName} onChange={handlers[i]} />
          ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo fields={fields} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How i would handle this is by creating a `state` and passing it as a dependency to the `useCallback` hook like:

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState({'field1': "", 'field2': "", 'field3': ""});

const handleChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
  console.log(`${fieldName}: `, e.target.value);
  if(e.target.id === "field1") {
    let newFields = {...fields};
    fields.field1 = e.target.value;
    setFields(newFields);
  }
}, [fields])

return (
  <>
    {fields.map((x) => <Component onChange={handleChange(x)} />}
  </>
)
```

Hope this works for you.